# Wordpress: own rewrite rule for pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pagination

is it possible to create the following redirect rule:

> http://xyz.com/page/2/

should redirect to

> http://xyz.com/?page=2

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a [Mod Rewrite Generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/), and put that in your htaccess file

And in your htaccess file, it would look something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

You can use this website to generate rewrite code: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Edit: seems like I was a little too late..

Comment: I modified the code a little bit:
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/$ /blog/?page=$1 [L,R=301]